# How to build an array[string] from an unknown amount of arrays PHP

Tags: php, algorithm, recurrence

I doubt this is the right way to do this.

What happens?

You feed a method any amount of arrays...

```
[
    'jupiter',
    'saturn',
]
[
    'is',
    'was',
]
[
    'old',
    'big',
    'loved',
]
```

and creates...

```
[
  'jupiter is big',
  'jupiter is loved',
  'jupiter is old',
  'jupiter was big',
  'jupiter was loved',
  'jupiter was old',
  'saturn is big',
  'saturn is loved',
  'saturn is old',
  'saturn was big',
  'saturn was loved',
  'saturn was old',
]
```

How should you do this?

Stackoverflow likes attempts, so here you go

My method currently has two recurring functions (with nested for loops) and a dozen other for loops between  Not what you picture being the fastest way to achieve this. I did first try using clever maths but began confusing myself. If you have a much nicer solution, please can you explain it too!

Thank-you for your time.

Here's my working code:

```
<?php

function generateList(...$arrays)
{
    // Use first array to generate a starting point
    $result = [...array_map(function($item){return [$item => []];}, $arrays[0])];

    // Adds a new keyed array to the end of every existing empty array
    function addToEndChild($object, $string){
        if (is_array($object) && count($object) == 0){
            return [$string => []];
        }
        foreach ($object as $index => $item){
            $object[$index] = addToEndChild($item, $string);
        }
        return $object;
    };

    // Flattens array back down using the keys as values
    function flatten($array, $prefix = '', $depth = 0) {
        $result = [];
        foreach($array as $key => $value) {
            if (is_int($key) == false){
                $result[] = $key;
            }
            $flat = flatten($value, $prefix . $key . '.', $depth + 1);
            $result = array_merge($result, $depth == 0 ? [$flat] : $flat);
        }
        return $result;
    }

    // Loop through remaining arrays and build up nested array
    foreach (array_slice($arrays, 1) as $array){
        $layer = [];
        foreach ($array as $item){
            $layer[] = addToEndChild($result, $item);
        }
        $result = array_merge(...$layer);
    }

    // Flatten down
    $finalResult = flatten($result);

    // Convert layers into strings
    foreach ($finalResult as $index => $item){
        $finalResult[$index] = implode(' ', $item);
    }

    // Sort alphabetically
    asort($finalResult);
    
    return $finalResult;
}

$a = [
    'jupiter',
    'saturn',
];
$b = [
    'is',
    'was',
];
$c = [
    'old',
    'big',
    'loved',
];

var_dump(generateList($a, $b, $c));
```

Comment: It would be a more appropriate to ask this on [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: This will be useful for others trying to build an array from an unknown amount of arrays the right way...? I couldn't find a previously existing question yet

Comment: Maybe you can lookup some optimizations for "Permutation".

Comment: Thank-you, Permutation looks like a great place to start  @MarkusZeller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my code with just one recursive function. Also it takes a matrix as a parameter instead of N arrays.

```
function generateList($data){
    if (count($data) == 0){
        return null;
    }

    $current = $data[0];
    $left = array_slice($data, 1);
    $permutations = generateList($left);

    $r = [];
    foreach($current as $item){
        if ($permutations){
            foreach ($permutations as $rest) {
                $r[] = $item . ' ' . $rest;
            }
        }
        else {
            $r[] = $item;
        }
    }
    return $r;
}

$data = [
    ['jupiter', 'saturn'],
    ['is', 'was'],
    ['old', 'big', 'loved']
];
var_dump(generateList($data));
```